# what is difference between rem==0 and rem=0 in this code?

Tags: c++

THEY WERE ASKING ME TO ADD SOMETHING
.I DINT KNOW WHAT TO ADD.THIS LINE IS A WASTE.
SUGGEST ME AN EDIT

#include 
    using namespace std;

```
typedef long long lli;

lli mod = 1000000007;

int n;
char a[200000 + 10];
lli dp[200000 + 10][9];

lli solve(int pos, int rem)
{
    if (pos == n) //**HERE** 
        return (rem == 0);

    if (dp[pos][rem] != -1)
        return dp[pos][rem];

    dp[pos][rem] = 0;
    if (pos + 1 <= n)
        dp[pos][rem] = solve(pos + 1, (rem * 10 + (a[pos] - '0')) % 8);
    if (pos + 1 <= n)
        dp[pos][rem] += solve(pos + 1, rem);
    dp[pos][rem] %= mod;

    return dp[pos][rem];
}
```

Comment: rem==0 means compare rem value with zero and rem = 0 means zero assign on rem variable.

Comment: so if(rem==0) is true then it will return 1?

Comment: Yes, if true return 1 and if false return 0.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions addressing the very basics of a programming language are not helpful for any visitor of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between the 2 is a difference between the assignment operator and the comparison operator.

`rem == 0` is an example of a comparison operator, because a comparison is being made to see if the value of rem is zero or not. In this case, it will **NOT** set rem to zero!

If rem is equal to zero, then the following line in your code:

```
    return (rem == 0);
```

is the same as

```
    return true; // or return 1, both mean the same thing in the bool expression. It returns true as the statement is true
```

**However** if this is *not* the case, that rem is not equal to 0, then:

```
    return (rem == 0);
```

Will be the same as:

```
    return false; // or return 0, because the statement is false because rem is not equal to 0
```

---

Moving on to what `rem = 0` does is that it simply assigns the variable on the left of the equal sign(i.e rem) the value that is on the right of the equal sign (i.e 0). This statement makes no comparison; it merely is used to assign values.

Answer (score 1):

`rem==0` returns either true or false ,

Eg :

```
 rem=5;
 rem=rem-5;
 if(a==0)
   cout<<"YES";
```

whereas

```
rem=0;
```

makes the rem variable have a value of 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
rem == 0
```

Checks if the value of `rem` operand is equal to `Zero` or not, if `yes` then condition becomes true.

```
rem=0;
```

Simple Assigns value from right side to left side operand.

Answer (score 1):

there is a big difference between '==' and '=' operator.

'==' is a RELATIONAL OPERATOR

It checks if the values of two operands are equal or not. If yes, then the condition becomes true else it becomes false.

```
POSSIBLE USE
    1. In if else loops
```

'=' is an ASSIGNMENT OPERATOR

It assigns values from right side operands to left side operand.

```
POSSIBLE USE
    1. During variable declaration and value assignment
```